# ByRef Argument Mismatch with VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, variables, methods, parameters

I have a Let property defined as:

```
Public Property Let Set_ChanArray_Enabled1(i As Integer, j As Integer, choice As Boolean)
    ChanArray(i, j).Enabled1 = choice
End Property
```

In a sub defined in the same object module, I attempt to do the following:

```
For j = 4 To 44
    Me.Set_ChanArray_Enabled1(j, 1) = True
    Me.Set_ChanArray_Enabled1(j, 3) = True
Next j
```

But VBE gives me a ByRef argument mismatch pointing to the j passed into

```
Me.Set_ChanArray_Enabled1(j, 1) = True
```

I have defined both j and the parameter passed into the method as integers so I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: You aren't passing in the right parameters.  You wrote your function to accept 3 parameters (i, j, choice) and you are calling it with (i, j) = choice.  Try calling it like this  `Me.Set_ChanArray_Enabled1(j, 1, True)`

Comment: I've tried the code you suggested before but it doesn't work. If I replace j with an ordinary integer (ex. 3) the code works. I think the error has something to do with passing in an integer variable.

Comment: Ok, I just researched a little and you can call it the way you have it written.  But, are you passing your array index in the right order?  Your Let property has the order as (i,j) and when you call it you're passing (j,i)?  Have you tried putting ByVal in you're function parameters?

Comment: hm...putting byval seemed to make it work! Didn't know why I didn't try that earlier. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error indicates something is wrong with the typing of `j` (i.e its not of type integer).

Have you declared it in a statement like; `dim j, i as integer`? If so then only `i` is an integer (you need to repeat `as integer`).

(Using `byval` appears to "fix" this because its pass-by-copy semantics allow VBA to perform an automatic type conversion to integer before calling `Set_ChanArray_Enabled1`).